# Is it safe to upgrade Google Play Services version and how to test if everything is okay?

Tags: android

In my app I have these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
```

Is it safe to upgrade to 8.4 and how do I test (if testing is needed)?

Comment: If the project builds fine and seems to run fine, it works.

Comment: upgradation means fixing bugs in previous version....so go for new1.

Answer (score 1):

When i updated GPS to version upper than 8.3 it broke my release! Becouse it requiers applicatioId= in gradle.
 here is issue:
https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=784

Comment: how did it break it? Straight forwardly or via nondeterministic behavior